# How to maintain my body without fat and reduce belly?

Tags: workout, workout-routines, bodybuilding, body-fat, bellyfat

I've been going to the gym for the past 3 years. Although my body shape has changed a lot, my weight has been stable 70kg for this period. For example, my biceps has developed a lot, but I was unable to reduce my belly.
I'm too lazy to do abdominal exercises.

How can I reduce my belly fat?

```
Food Structure:

Breakfast : black gram dal or Green gram dal or it may be Chickpea.
Lunch : Rice with Fish
Dinner : Rice with Fish
```

Comment: I won't comment on the nutritional insufficiency in your diet. What I will say is that by "being too lazy" to do abdominal exercises, you are inviting such things as back pain and other muscular imbalance ailments down the line. All muscles should be worked so as to avoid imbalance and imbalance injuries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sadly you cannot reduce fat on just one spot, you have to reduce your overall body fat. This will reduce belly fat as well in the long run.

It might help if you explained what kind of exercises you are doing, but a generalized approach would be to do more cardio workouts, as these kind of workouts burn more fat compared to weight lifting. (Always be careful when counting calories though, they are nothing more than a rough estimate).

Depending on your abilities and general fitness level I'd recommend that you maybe try to do some jogging additionally to your gym sessions. Other activities would be biking or swimming, but they are more time consuming than simple running. Try to add some minor sporting to your daily routine. If you go by bus, maybe exit one or two stations earlier and walk.

I think rice and fish is a good meal, but maybe try to change it a bit. Some people claim that eating carbohydrates in the evening isn't that good. Whether or not this is true, maybe change you dinner to contain more vegetables instead of rice. If you fry your fish, try to use less fat.

What are you drinking throughout the day? Many people don't realize that they are drinking soda (like coke) the whole day and how much sugar they consume this way, switch to water or tea.

At least do some exercises for the abdominal region. They might be, together with back and shoulder exercises, the most annoying exercises to do, as you don't see fast results here, but they are very important for your posture and overall strength.

Comment: I didnt do for back also. your point is correct. I will keep this in mind and to follow. I choose running to reduce my fat.

Answer (score 1):

I have been doing this routine for a while and it is high intensity and concentrates on belly fat:

1. 30 seconds blast off push-ups
2. 30 seconds plank
3. 30 seconds bucking hops
4. 30 seconds side plank (left and right)
5. 30 seconds bird dogs
6. L pull-ups until you can't pull up.

3 or 4 sets

Comment: You cannot spot reduce fat. What you are doing is intensely working the muscles underneath the fat. This has an effect of tightening the muscles in the area, which visually can make it appear as though the belly is less, but you cannot target fat loss in an area by doing muscle work in the same area.

Comment: Interesting I did not know that. Thanks!