# Skinny male getting belly fat, how to gain weight and mass from this condition

Tags: weightlifting, fat, bellyfat, home-exercise

I am 25 years old my height is 5'8" and weight is 58K.

I went to gym for gaining muscle in 2011 and my progress was very slow, after couple of months continuing gym, I left it.

For last six months my lower belly is getting big. And I am feeling weak now a days.

I want to gain some weight with mass and want to loose my belly fat(its look really odd).

I have read couple of fitness blogs they suggest to go to gym and do weight training. But now its not possible for me to go to a gym(nearest gym is far away from home and I dont have much time to go there).

What I can do, I can buy light(cheap) instruments and also can arrange better food. And I can do some home exercise.

Do you guys have any specific suggestions? How can I recover from this situation?

I dont need six pack, what I want to achieve like a better shape with some mass and strength.Btw I live a hacker's life style(lots of coca cola, beers and chocolates, pizzas)

Please share your experience, I am really worried in this condition.

Comment: [This question](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/8052/how-to-maintain-my-body-without-fat-and-reduce-belly) might help you.

Comment: Lots of coke and beers, and you gave up the gym ... are you expecting some magic pill?

Comment: No, I am not expecting a magic pill, expecting "home exercise list" and food habit that can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is way too generic, the answer to your problem is in lifestyle advice, not really an exercise plan ... try doing two things to start

[Stop eating and drinking rubbish](http://www.nowloss.com/foods-not-to-eat-when-trying-to-lose-weight-dieting.htm)
[Do some body weight exercise](http://www.nerdfitness.com/blog/2009/12/09/beginner-body-weight-workout-burn-fat-build-muscle/)

Stick with it for at least 2 month without cheating or slacking and come back to ask more specific questions if that did not help you lose some belly fat and build strength. Good luck.